# Command executed differently from terminal or in bash script

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to automate a backup script with attic, but I'm stuck on this issue: the actual attic command performs differently when executed from the script and when executed directly in the terminal.

The script builds and executes the command:

```
/usr/bin/attic create --stats --verbose --exclude '/home/.cache' /media/attic-backup/paolo.attic::2016-08-27 /home
```

the command outputs the files backuped up from attic:

```
/home
/home/.attic
/home/.attic/keys
/home/.cache
/home/git
/home/git/.bash_history
etc etc
```

The `/home/.cache` directory should have been skipped...

However, if I execute the same command from the terminal I get:

```
$ /usr/bin/attic create --stats --verbose --exclude '/home/.cache' /media/attic-backup/paolo.attic::2016-08-27 /home
/home
/home/.attic
/home/.attic/keys
/home/git
/home/git/.bash_history
etc etc
```

Now the `/home/.cache` directory has been skipped.

It's not a matter of sudo.

Why the command in the script behaves differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say the script "builds" the command, do you mean it stores it in a string (variable), and then tries to execute the string as a command? If so, putting quotes inside the string (`'/home/.cache'`) won't do what you expect, because the quotes are treated as data and passed to the command as part of the argument, rather than being parsed and removed before it's passed as an argument. Essentially, this means that rsync was being told to exclude `'/home/.cache'` rather than just `/home/.cache`. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more info.

If you're trying to build the command piece-by-piece, usually the best way to do it is with an array. Something like this:

```
atticcmd=(/usr/bin/attic create --stats --verbose --exclude '/home/.cache' /media/attic-backup/paolo.attic::2016-08-27 /home)
"${atticcmd[@]}"
```

Or you can build only a part of it in an array:

```
atticopts=(--stats --verbose)
for e in "${excludes[@]}"; do
    atticopts+=(--exclude "$e")
done
/usr/bin/attic create "${atticopts[@]}" /media/attic-backup/paolo.attic::2016-08-27 /home
```

Comment: I created the array ATTIC_COMMAND_ELEMENTS with elemens of the form `--exclude '/home/.cache'`, but  `/usr/bin/attic create "${ATTIC_COMMAND_ELEMENTS[@]}" "$REPOSITORY::"\`date +%Y-%m-%d--%H.%M\` /home` doesn't work, I get  `attic create: error: argument ARCHIVE: "--exclude '/home/.cache'": No archive specified`. Why?!?

Comment: @PaoloBenvenuto "--exclude" and "/home/.cache" should be two separate elements (since they'll be separate arguments to attic), and the single-quotes should *not* be included in the value -- quotes go *around* data, not *in* data. Note that as shell arguments, `'/home/.cache'`, `"/home/.cache"`, and `/home/.cache` are all exactly equivalent -- the quotes (if any) influence how the string is parsed (whether various kinds of substitutions and expansions are done, none of which are relevant here), and then removed before the argument is passed to the command.

Comment: Also, you can use `set -x` to make the shell print the command it's about to execute, showing what it thinks is happening. Or rather, it prints an equivalent command line, which can be a bit confusing. I'd try using `set -x` in an interactive shell, running the command (the one that works) manually, and looking at how the shell interprets it. Then add `set -x` to the script just before the command that's failing (and `set +x just after it), and compare to see what's different.